# prevent OrderedDict from splitting single string value into characters during iteration

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I would like to make an `OrderedDict` with a string for each key and a list of strings for each value.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# Compare a dict with an OrderedDict
someDict = dict(a = ["foo","bar"], b = ["baz"])
someOrderedDict = OrderedDict([("a",("foo","bar")),("b",("baz"))])
```

I need to iterate over this dictionary with access to both the key and the values.  On a vanilla dictionary, this is simply:

```
for k,v in someDict.items():
    for eachv in v:
        print("do something with key = " + k + " and value = " + eachv)
# returns the desired output:
# do something with key = a and value = foo
# do something with key = a and value = bar
# do something with key = b and value = baz
```

(If this can be done in a comprehension, please enlighten me -- I couldn't figure out how to do without losing access to the key.)

When I try this on the `OrderedDict` I get:

```
for k,v in someOrderedDict.items():
    for eachv in v:
        print("do something with key = " + k + " and value = " + eachv) 
# results in undesirable splitting of value "baz" into ["b","a","z"]:
# do something with key = a and value = foo
# do something with key = a and value = bar
# do something with key = b and value = b
# do something with key = b and value = a
# do something with key = b and value = z
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `,` after `"baz"` so it can get interpreted as a tuple instead of a single `str` during the `for` loop:

```
someOrderedDict = OrderedDict([("a",("foo","bar")),("b",("baz",))])
```

Then, iteration works fine grabbing the single element of the tuple `baz`:

```
for k,v in someOrderedDict.items():
    for eachv in v:
        print("do something with key = " + k + " and value = " + eachv)
do something with key = b and value = baz
do something with key = a and value = foo
do something with key = a and value = bar
```

The same could be achieved by wrapping the values in `[]`:

```
[("a", ["foo","bar"]),("b", ["baz"])]
```

---

**Even better**, if you already have the dictionary available, just expand (unpack) the dictionary `someDict` in `someOrderedDict` by utilizing the `**` syntax:

```
someOrderedDict = OrderedDict(**someDict)
```

it works equally well and *looks much more compact and clean*.

Comment: Thanks -- I am accepting this because the `**` may be useful to other users, but it's worth noting that if keeping the original order matters (which is why I want to use `OrderedDict`) then one needs to use the original construction.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 I remember seeing an issue on the python tracker for keeping the order while unpacking, might be added soon too, I'll see if I can find a url for it and check its status.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you're assigning a string (`("baz")`) to the `b` key, rather than a tuple (`("baz",)`) or list of strings.

Instead of

```
someOrderedDict = OrderedDict([("a",("foo","bar")),("b",("baz"))])
```

try

```
someOrderedDict = OrderedDict([("a",("foo","bar")),("b",("baz",))])
```

(Note the new comma.)